# How to search and replace strings in long text which needs to run on shell

Tags: bash, shell

i have long text in which each execution run i need to search and replace same string in this long text ;
my question is what is the best way to search and replace this text and preview it before running again
for example :

```
ansible-playbook ~/main.yml --extra-vars "selected_playbook=start_here.yml url=http://app.zip name='FOO_1' tag='FOO_1' region=us-east-1 owner='FOO_1' DB_USERNAME=FOO_1"
```

i like to replace all FOO_1 to FOO_2

Comment: Use a variable?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you can put in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz replace-string
zle -N replace-string-pattern replace-string
bindkey '\er' replace-string-pattern
```

And then upon pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, `zle` will prompt you for the pattern and replacement.

You could even use things like `FOO_(<->)` as pattern and `FOO_$((match+1))` as replacement to replace all `FOO_<number>`s with `FOO_<number+1>`.

And then since `replace-string` will reuse the same pattern+replacement by default (if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>), that makes it easy to re-run the same command with the number increased each time, though for that you may prefer doing things like:

```
for n (FOO_{1..10}) ansible-playbook ~/main.yml --extra-vars "selected_playbook=start_here.yml url=http://app.zip name='$n' tag='$n' region=us-east-1 owner='$n' DB_USERNAME=$n"
```

Comment: its standard bash shell no zsh for me

Comment: @user63898. No worries. I can't help but to feel a bit sorry for people in your case. That reminds me of the 90s when some people were forced to use csh as it was what everbody else was using and had been using for decades.  I'll still keep the answer around as it could be useful to other people who don't suffer from that same constraint.